# Display on sale variation saving amount for WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I am having a custom plugin which is used to show accessories. I want to display total savings of main product and accessories combined. my saving works if the main product is simple if the main product is variable the savings shows null. can someone update my code, please

I tried this code to show saving but it is just working for simple products

```
function you_save_echo_product() {
    global $product;

    // works for Simple and Variable type
    $regular_price  = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true ); // 36.32
    $sale_price     = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true ); // 24.99

    if( !empty($sale_price) ) {

        $saved_amount       = $regular_price - $sale_price;
        $currency_symbol    = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

        $percentage = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
        ?>
            <p id="saving_total_price">You Save: <span class="symbol"><?php echo $currency_symbol; ?></span> <span class="amount"><?php echo $saved_amount; ?></span>.00</p>                
        <?php       
    } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'you_save_echo_product', 11 );
```

I expect to show total savings for my accessories with the main product as a variable

Answer (score 4):

I have revisited your code as it's is a bit outdated and old… On variable products there is 2 prices, a price range and the selected variation price, so you need something completely different to display the saving amount of the selected variation price.

I have added also the saving percentage (that you can remove if you don't need it).

```
// For simple products
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 11 );
function simple_product_saving_amount() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        $active_price  = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );

        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $regular_price * 100 );

        echo '<p id="saving_total_price">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';
    }
}

// For product variations (on variable products)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variable_product_saving_amount', 10, 3 );
function variable_product_saving_amount( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
        $saved_amount  = $data['display_regular_price'] - $data['display_price'];
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $data['display_regular_price'] * 100 );

        $data['price_html'] .= '<p id="saving_total_price">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.